# spring batch api request on wait

Tags: multithreading, spring-batch

I have written a simple spring batch project where

1. API to execute job: returns job ID on job launch
   reads/processes/writes from/to DB in multithread parallel processing

(Launching the job asynchronously to get the job ID in advance so I can poll the status of the job from another API request.)

2. API to poll the status of the job with respect to the job ID passed.

Polling api works smoothly if job step's throttle limit is 7 or less.

However, if throttle limit is more than 7, job execution continues but polling api will be on wait till read/process releases.

Have also tried a simple api which simply returns String instead of polling but that goes on wait too.

Sample of the code as shown below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfig {
    private int core = 200;
    
    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get(SC_Constants.JOB)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(new Listener(transDAO))
                .start(step_processRecords()
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(this.core);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(this.core);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(this.core);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("threadExecutor");

        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcPagingItemReader<Transaction> itemReader(...) { 
        JdbcPagingItemReader<Transaction> itemReader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<Transaction>();
        ...
        return itemReader;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemProcessor<Transaction,Transaction> processor()  {
        return new Processor();
    }
    
    
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter<Transaction> writer(...) {
        return new Writer();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Step step3_processRecords() throws Exception {
        
        return stepBuilderFactory.get(SC_Constants.STEP_3_PROCESS_RECORDS)
                .<Transaction,Transaction>chunk(this.chunk)             
                .reader(itemReader(null,null,null))
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer(null,null,null))
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .throttleLimit(20)
                .build();
    }
    
    
}
```

file that extends DefaultBatchConfigurer has below:

```
@Override
public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() {
   SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
   jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
   SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor exec = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
   exec.setConcurrencyLimit(concurrency_limit);
   jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(exec);
   return jobLauncher;
}
```

Edit:

polling api code snippet

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/getJobStatus")
    public Response getJobStatus(@RequestBody String body){
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(body);               
    Long jobId = jsonObject.get("jobId"); 
    jobExecution = jobExplorer.getJobExecution(jobId); 
        batchStatus = jobExecution.getStatus().getBatchStatus(); 
        write_count = jobExecution.getStepExecutions().iterator().next().getWriteCount(); 
        responseDto.setJob_id(jobId); 
        responseDto.setWrite_count(write_count); 
        responseDto.setStatus(batchStatus.name()); 
        return responseDto;
    }
```

Second edit:
sharing a snippet of the jobrepository setting: using postgres jdbc job repository.

```
@Component
public class SpringBatchConfigurer extends DefaultBatchConfigurer{
...
@PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {

        try {
            BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
            dataSource.setUsername(username);
            dataSource.setPassword(password);

            dataSource.setUrl(dsUrl + "?currentSchema=public");

            dataSource.setInitialSize(3);
            dataSource.setMinIdle(1);
            dataSource.setMaxIdle(3);
            dataSource.addConnectionProperty("maxConnLifetimeMillis", "30000");

            this.transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);

            JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
            factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
            factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();
            this.jobRepository = factory.getObject();
            
            SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
            jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
            jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
            this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BatchConfigurationException(e);
        }
}
```

Third Edit: Tried passing it as a local variable under this step. polling works but now, job execution is not happening. No threads generated. No processing is happening.

```
    @Bean
    public Step step3_processRecords() throws Exception {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(this.core_size);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(this.max_pool_size);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(this.queue_capacity);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("threadExecutor");

        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step3")
                .<Transaction,Transaction>chunk(this.chunk)             
                .reader(itemReader(null,null,null))
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer(null,null,null))
                .taskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor)
                .throttleLimit(20)
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share more details about your polling API? Is it running in the same JVM? If yes, are the threads running this polling API borrowed from the same pool that is used to execute your step? If this is the case, then probably no more threads are available from the pool (if they are all used to execute your step) to execute your polling requests, hence the wait.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. new to multithreading. 
It is running in the same JVM.
How do i check if the polling API is borrowing from the same pool?

P.S: if I deploy a copy of this project's war (project1.war, project1_copy.war) in the same tomcat and try to poll from the other war, polling works.

Comment: If you share the code that you use to poll the job repository, I can tell you if it uses the same thread pool or not. And your experiment of deploying and polling from a separate war and that it works confirms what I was suspecting in my previous comment: both the polling API and the step are using the same pool of threads, so when you increase the throttle limit, no more threads are available for the polling API, hence the wait.

Comment: hi, this is in the job polling api:

jobExecution =  jobExplorer.getJobExecution(jobId);
batchStatus = jobExecution.getStatus().getBatchStatus();
write_count = jobExecution.getStepExecutions().iterator().next().getWriteCount();  

responseDto.setJob_id(jobId);
responseDto.setWrite_count(write_count);    
responseDto.setStatus(batchStatus.name()); 

return responseDto;

however, as i said in the main post, even a simple api like return "Hello world" String also remains in wait.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there, no in comments as it is not readable. Is this part of a web controller? If it's the case, it could be that Spring is using your `taskExecutor` to serve web requests, which would explain the issue.

Comment: have edited the question and added the polling api snippet. more than threads, is there any limit of 8 somewhere within the spring batch/ spring boot framework? datasource or threads in any of these?

Comment: The default throttle limit in a multi-threaded step in spring batch is 4, but I see you set it to 20. Which job repository are you using? The Map-based job repository is known to have limitations with multi-threading.

Comment: Hi. Using the JDBC based job repository. Using our Postgres DB for the same.  Have added the code snippet in the main question under edit sections. have set two datasources. read/process/write happens in one datasource - Snowflake and job repository is set to another datasource - Postgres

Comment: ok, in that case, I don't see another explanation for that behaviour other than the one I shared previously. Try to create the task executor as a local variable in the step definition method (and not as a spring bean) to make sure that the step is not using the same task executor that is executing web requests.

Comment: Tried passing it as a local variable under the step as in `Third Edit`. Polling api works but now, job execution is not happening. No threads generated. No processing is happening.